# How to send a key without triggering any code assigned _to that key_?

Tags: autohotkey

So I have

```
`::
` Up::
    IfEqual, A_ThisHotkey, %A_PriorHotkey%,   return
    Send ^!i
Return
```

and

```
^'::`
```

But it doesn't work because upon pressing `^' (ctrl+')` it doesn't send ` but instead executes `^!i`. How do I make just send the character ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to prevent that the output of one hotkey triggers another. Add a $ sign like this.

```
$'::
```

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#prefixdollar